# cakephp3のアソシエーション

Tags: cakephp

cakephp3で下記２つのテーブルのアソシエーションを定義しようと思っています。

テーブル１：usersテーブル
ユーザーの特性を定義するテーブル。

テーブル２：languagesテーブル
プログラミング言語を定義するマスターテーブル。

usersテーブルには、main_languageとsub_languageというカラムがあって、languagesテーブルに定義してあるidを参照する形になっています。

この場合、cakephp3ではどのようにアソシエーションの定義をすれば良いでしょうか？よろしくおねがいいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/121244

Answer (score 1):

`users` テーブルに対応するTableクラス `UsersTable`, `languages` テーブルに対応するTableクラス `LanguagesTable` は既に定義済みとします。

質問のテーブル設計の場合、`users` → `languages` の関係はbelongsToになります。

[belongsTo アソシエーション | アソシエーション - モデル同士を繋ぐ - 3.5](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/orm/associations.html#belongsto)

`UsersTable`の`initialize()`メソッドに次のようにしてリレーションを定義します。

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        // ...
        $this->belongsTo('MainLanguage', [ // リレーション名（任意の名前を指定）
            'className' => 'Languages', // 相手先のテーブルクラス名
            'foreignKey' => 'main_language', // 当該のテーブル上の外部キーの名前
            'propertyName' => 'main_language_obj', // エンティティ化したときに紐付けるプロパティ名（任意の名前を指定）
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('SubLanguage', [
            'className' => 'Languages',
            'foreignKey' => 'sub_language',
            'propertyName' => 'sub_language_obj',
        ]);
    }
}
```

上記の指定をすることで、以下のようにして取得できます。

```
$user = $this->Users->find('all')
    ->contain(['MainLanguage', 'SubLanguage']) // contain句を忘れずに
    ->first();
// main_language の languages.name を参照
$user->main_language_obj->name;
// sub_language の languages.name を参照
$user->sub_language_obj->name;
```

なお、CakePHPの規約に沿うのであれば、usersテーブルの外部キーとなる `main_language`, `sub_language` は、  `main_language_id`, `sub_language_id` とすべきで、プロパティ名に `main_language`, `sub_language` を使用した方が自然です。

Comment: さらに言えば、`users ` → `users_languages` → `languages` のように紐付け用の結合テーブルを作ってbelongsToMany(hasMany through)リレーションで構築した方が、紐付け数の増減、紐付けに追加の情報などを乗せやすくなるので、私であればこちらでテーブル設計します。

Comment: ありがとうございます！Cakeのドキュメントにそのまま書いてありましたね！お手数をおかけしました。